# powershell: how to ls dirA,dirB -rec | group FileName,VersionInfo.ProductVersion | ft -auto ...?

Tags: powershell

See what I'm trying to do there?  Naturally, it doesn't work.

I want to get a table of filenames and version info (product name, version) in a couple of directories, along with counts of duplicates.

One problem is I can't seem to reach inside the results of the group-object cmdlet, so the following also doesn't work:

```
ls VisitRecord-1/Release,Dispo-1/Release -rec `
    | % {@{FileName=$_.Name; ProductName=$_.VersionInfo.ProductName; ProductVersion=$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion } `
        | New-HashObject} `
    | group FileName,ProductName,ProductVersion `
    | % {@{Count=$_.Count; FileName=$_.Group.FileName}}
```

because $_.Group.FileName seems to return null (or empty string).

What am I missing?  Any ideas?  (I'm running version 2 of PowerShell.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** I'm leaving my original answer, because the workaround it shows and the ensuing discussion help understand what's really going on. However, the optimal solution is at the very end.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** (which works but isn't the best way to do it)

This seems to be a bug in PowerShell 2.0. I tried your code in 3.0 and it worked fine (except I used `New-Object -Property` instead of `| New-HashObject`, because I don't have that extension installed and it seems superfluous to me).

For some odd reason, in 2.0, you can't read any of the **NoteProperty** properties of the **GroupInfo** objects returned by **Group-Object**. It works if you use **Select-Object**, though. Replace your last line with this:

```
| %{@{Count=$_.Count; FileName=$_.Group | select -expand FileName}}
```

On a sidenote, as I mentioned above, I'm not sure I see the value of the **New-HashObject** extension. This works just as well, using only native PowerShell (as a replacement for the second and third lines of your code):

```
| %{New-Object PSObject -Property @{FileName=$_.Name; ProductName=$_.VersionInfo.ProductName; ProductVersion=$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion} `
```

---

**UPDATE**

The workaround above works, but for the wrong reason. I thought of `$_.Group.FileName` as an attempt to read a **NoteProperty** of a **GroupInfo** object, but after reading Keith Hill's comment I realized that it's **$_** that's the **GroupInfo** object, and **$_.Group** is a property of that object which is a collection. The reason the OP's code works in PowerShell 3.0 is that the collection has only one object, so enumerating a single property of the collection (**FileName**) returns a single string rather than an array.

However, the fact that it's a collection actually makes the solution simpler. Just add a `[0]` after `.Group` to retrieve the first (and only) object in the collection:

```
| % {@{Count=$_.Count; FileName=$_.Group[0].FileName}}
```

Comment: Looks like the surrounding `$()` wasn't needed. After seeing Keith Hill's answer, I tried my version without it, and that works too.

Comment: It is not a bug.  PowerShell V3 added member enumeration which is why $Collection.Property ($_.Group.Filename) works in V3 and higher.

Comment: @KeithHill Ah, I see what you're saying. I overlooked that he's not trying to read a property of the **GroupInfo** object itself, because **$_** is the **GroupInfo** object, and **$_.Group** is a property of that **GroupInfo** object which is a collection. So his code doesn't work in PS 2.0 because he's trying to read a member property of a collection, and it works in 3.0 only because the collection happens to have only one object in every case. In that case, I have an even better answer--simply add `[0]` after `.Group`, that's the only modification needed. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It works as-is on V4.  You may need an extra foreach on V2 and below e.g.:

```
ls VisitRecord-1/Release,Dispo-1/Release -rec `
    | % {@{FileName=$_.Name; ProductName=$_.VersionInfo.ProductName; ProductVersion=$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion } `
    | New-HashObject} `
    | group FileName,ProductName,ProductVersion `
    | % {@{Count=$_.Count; FileName=$_.Group | %{$_.FileName}}}
```

Comment: Yep, it works this way as well, I just tested it. I guess it's essentially the same idea...

Answer (score 0):

Previous two answers were excellent, many thanks.  Wish I could mark them both as answers.  Answering my own question so I can drop some code in, which I don't think I can do in a comment.

My solution (yay, eating lunch and tinkering):

```
ls VisitRecord-1/Release,Dispo-1/Release -rec `
    | % {@{FileName=$_.Name; ProductName=$_.VersionInfo.ProductName; ProductVersion=$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion }} `
    | New-HashObject `
    | group FileName,ProductName,ProductVersion `
    | % {$grp = $_.Name -split ', '; @{Count=$_.Count; FileName=$grp[0]; ProductName=$grp[1]; ProductVersion=$grp[2]}} `
    | New-HashObject `
    | Select Count,FileName,ProductName,ProductVersion `
    | sort ProductName,FileName `
    | ft -auto
```

Still seems a little overkill, but I'll just consider it bug workaround.

I love PSCX but I do get confused about what's native PS and what's PSCX.  I think a win for New-HashObject *might* be that it can take a stream of hashtables on its input and produce a stream of objects.  Possible performance gain?

Anyway, glad to find it's a bug in PS 2.0.  I guess that's a good-enough reason to upgrade. :)

---

**Edit after installing PS 3.0**

Rewritten command line:

```
ls VisitRecord-1/Release,Dispo-1/Release -rec `
    | % {@{FileName=$_.Name; `
            ProductName=$_.VersionInfo.ProductName; `
            ProductVersion=$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion }} `
    | New-HashObject `
    | group FileName,ProductName,ProductVersion `
    | % {@{Count=$_.Count; `
            GroupCount=$_.Group.Count; `
            FileName=$_.Group[0].FileName; `
            ProductName=$_.Group[0].ProductName; `
            ProductVersion=$_.Group[0].ProductVersion}} `
    | New-HashObject `
    | select Count,GroupCount,FileName,ProductName,ProductVersion `
    | sort ProductName,FileName `
    | ft -auto
```

Threw in GroupCount for illustration, added [0] to Group references.  Maybe that would have made it work under PS 2.0, but there's no going back (for me) now. :)

**(Edit: And after all that, the above does work under PS 2.0, after all.)**

More than you ever wanted to know about Group-Object:

```
ls VisitRecord-1/Release,Dispo-1/Release -rec `
    | % {@{FileName=$_.Name; ProductName=$_.VersionInfo.ProductName; ProductVersion=$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion }} `
    | New-HashObject `
    | group FileName,ProductName,ProductVersion `
    | ? {($_.Count -gt 1) -and ($_.Group[0].ProductName -ne $Null)} `
    | select -first 1 `
    | fl

Name   : Infragistics4.Shared.v13.1.dll, Infragistics4.Shared, 13.1.20131.2060
Count  : 2
Group  : {@{ProductVersion=13.1.20131.2060; FileName=Infragistics4.Shared.v13.1.dll; ProductName=Infragistics4.Shared},
         @{ProductVersion=13.1.20131.2060; FileName=Infragistics4.Shared.v13.1.dll; ProductName=Infragistics4.Shared}}
Values : {Infragistics4.Shared.v13.1.dll, Infragistics4.Shared, 13.1.20131.2060}
```